# how to disable form based authentication and enable token based authentication in jasper

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, token, jasperserver

I'm developing Custom SSO for login into jasper reports and chose token based authentication.I placed "applicationContext-externalauth-preauth.xml" to web-inf/ folder.But my jasper is loading the login.html page even after that. So please help me how to disable login page and enable the token based authentication for successful implementation of SSO in jasper.

Comment: Not sure if I can help here but thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 0):

In token based authentication , jasper server don't show any login screen.
Your url should be like :

http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro?pp=u%3DSven|r%3DManager|o%3DEMEA,Sales|pa1%3DSweden